# How to solve "Library not loaded" error because of LocalAuthentication.framework?

Tags: ios7, xcode6

I can successfully run my app in IOS 8 but in IOS 7, my app crashes.

The message is:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/LocalAuthentication.framework/LocalAuthentication
  Referenced from: /Users/burakkilic/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A0210158-BC6C-43AA-9D85-AA8DE6115AAA/data/Applications/xxx
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
/System/Library/Frameworks/LocalAuthentication.framework/LocalAuthentication: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could *weak link* `LocalAuthentication.framework` and conditionally access the `LocalAuthentication` API at runtime.

The latter can be done by either:

1. Checking the iOS version you are running.
2. Using reflection to test for the presence of API methods (`respondsToSelector`, et al).